# How to display the DetailView after a search

Tags: iphone, xcode, filtering, predicate, detailview

I use predicate to filter a table.
It works very well and also to display the detailView for each cell.

But after a filtering it does not work to display the filtered list in the detailView.
The cell just turns blue when pressing it but does not shift to detailView.

What am I missing here?

The code looks like this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    Person *person;

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        person = [self.filteredPeople objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        person = [self.people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    }


    dvController.title = person.firstName;   

    dvController.price = person.sjuName;   

    dvController.link = person.sexName;    

    dvController.picture = [UIImage imageNamed:person.femName];   


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];

    [dvController release];
     dvController = nil;
}
```

Comment: So do you have 2 tableviews here?

Answer (score 1):

Here both the tableView are of different class so the can't be equal thus change your if condition as

```
if ([tableView class] != [UITableView class]) // if it's is of type UISearchResultsTableView
    {
        person = [self.filteredPeople objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        person = [self.people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    }
```

Comment: The table works fine and the filtered table, just when it comes to present the detailView after filtering, it does nothing. Have only one line with delegate in view did load, mySearchBar.delegate = self; is that not enough?

Comment: I just want to confirm that is this method is being called when you select a cell??????

Comment: When I press a cell the // - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath // presents the detailView and the if-else decides if it is the filtered list or the unfiltered list. If I remove the if-else it works as normal but I can't get the filtered to show in detailView, i.e. the "if" does nothing

Comment: Tried that now. The difference is that when unfiltered the detailView comes in but has no content. The filtered has not changed and the cell just gets blue when pressed and does nothing. Could it be something in the count of rows. The other values which is not going to the detailView is right thou, I mean icons in the cell and other names in it.

Comment: No crash. But I discovered something is wrong with the "if". It never is there, just goes to the else. That why nothing happens after a filter

Comment: please check what is self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView returning??? NSLOG it

Comment: I try but am not sure how to do it. I know hot to NSLog a variale but not what to log in this case

Comment: `NSLog("@%",self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView);` and `NSLog("@%",tableView);` use both the logs...

Comment: I already did that but a bit different. Yours did crash. But result is:<UITableView: 0x6004400; frame = (0 0; 320 416); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x533ed90>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
and <UISearchResultsTableView: 0x602fa00; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x53440f0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

Comment: Still not working. NSLog says now "UITableView" for both but it does not seem to jump to first condition anyhow. If I set, if(1==1) it goes right but trying a filter and the lines pop up as they should, the detailView does not push animate. Just the same if the detailView did not exist. Just turns blue, and nothing happens. frustrating.

Comment: It goes to filteredPeople after setting if(1==1) and then detailView works but contains no values (of course, I did no filtering) and the view is black instead of a picture

Comment: I found out that after filtering the method - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath is never used at all. Wonder where to put in the DetailView then??

Comment: It is working now. It was the delegate. Forgot I had set the searchdisplay programmatically and forgot about the delagate. Thanks for taking your time